# Updating Drupal 9.5 to Drupal 10 fails with php errors: what should php include path be?

Tags: composer, 10

I am attempting to update a Drupal 9.5 site to Drupal 10.
Upgrade status says 100% ready
PHP is 8.1.25
Webserver is nginx 1.18
MYSQL is 8.0.35-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 - (Ubuntu)

Following instructions here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/upgrading-a-composer-based-site

The composer update step completes, then php errors.

Details. Composer gets this far...

```
68/68 [============================] 100%
In FilesystemRepository.php line 163:

  file_get_contents(/srv/sid2/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/../InstalledVersions.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or
   directory
```

After that, any Composer or Drush command I try to execute does this...(srv/sid2/web is the document root for the site)

```
PHP Warning:  

    require(/srv/sid2/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions_include.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/sid2/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 82
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/srv/sid2/vendor/composer/../guzzlehttp/promises/src/functions_include.php' (include_path='/srv/sid2/vendor/pear/archive_tar:/srv/sid2/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/srv/sid2/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/srv/sid2/vendor/pear/pear_exception:.:/usr/share/php') in /srv/sid2/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:82
    Stack trace:
    #0 /srv/sid2/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(65): composerRequireadb589663ee65f2462c8612df87cae83()
    #1 /srv/sid2/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInitadb589663ee65f2462c8612df87cae83::getLoader()
    #2 /srv/sid2/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(58): include_once('...')
    #3 /srv/sid2/vendor/drush/drush/drush(4): require('...')
    #4 /srv/sid2/vendor/bin/drush(120): include('...')
    #5 {main}
      thrown in /srv/sid2/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 82
```

The site does not load of course.

What has me thinking I have a php include_path problem is this part: `(include_path='/srv/sid2/vendor/pear/archive_tar:/srv/sid2/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/srv/sid2/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/srv/sid2/vendor/pear/pear_exception:.:/usr/share/php')`

But I don't understand php and/or Composer well enough to know what's gone wrong here or what the include_path needs to be to allow PHP to find all the stuff it's looking for.

But maybe I'm on the wrong track?

The first error, failing to find InstalledVersions.php: The file exists, but it's in /vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer  not /vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/../
(By the way, what does "/../" mean?)

**Composer info:**

`which composer`, outside any Drupal projects, returns: `/usr/local/bin/composer`

`which composer` inside one of my other projects (not yet upgraded) returns `./vendor/bin/composer`

`composer why composer/composer` inside other projects returns
`drupal/core-dev  9.5.0  requires  composer/composer (^2.2.12)`

Inside a working project, `composer -V` indicates version 2.2.22.
Globally, I get 2.5.4

Inside the failed upgrade project, all composer commands (so far) result in the errors already noted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a composer issue. Normally composer is installed globally

```
which composer
```

should return /usr/local/bin/composer. This is a global path for Drupal even if Linux considers it as local. If it doesn't return a path outside of the Drupal project then follow the install instructions https://getcomposer.org/download/

If you have a composer dependency locally

```
composer why composer/composer
```

then composer is part of your project, probably because of the dev package. If you don't need it remove the dev package. Otherwise, update the local composer in an extra step before updating Drupal:

```
composer update composer/composer
```

Also, when running into composer problems first try to update the global composer:

```
composer self-update
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added composer info to the question. When I do `composer update composer/composer` inside a non-broken project, it says nothing to update. Globally, it updated from 2.5.4 to 2.6.5. The local one is 2.2.22.

Comment: It could be that you are not able to update composer/composer because of dependencies. Then remove composer/composer 2.2.22 by removing the dev package `composer remove drupal/core-dev` - You can re-install the dev package after the update if you need it.

Comment: Another way to avoid the problem in your case would be to remove `./vendor/bin/` from your .bashrc PATH variable.

Comment: composer remove drupal/core-dev generated errors.... `38/49 [=====================>------]  77%PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "React\Promise\RejectedPromise" not found in /srv/sid1/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php:30
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/sid1/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php(134): React\Promise\FulfilledPromise->then()
#1 /srv/sid1/vendor/react/promise/src/Promise.php(168): React\Promise\Promise::React\Promise\{closure}() ` etc.   (Another test site. This one has /src/sid1/web as doc root)

Comment: I'm adding my composer.json to the question. Something seems likely to be wrong in there.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a different issue if you can't even run a composer remove command before the update. I don't debug a broken composer project, I start a new project. Please remove the composer.json and keep the topic focused on the two conflicting composer binaries.

Comment: Removing composer.json from the question.     If it matters, I can do composer removes and updates fine on the 9.5 site, but it doesn't want to do a remove drupal/core-dev.  ... which is why I'm thinking there is something amiss in the json.

Comment: OK, you have then to avoid using the local composer 2.2.22 at any cost. If you can't remove the path to it in the shell environment variable $PATH access the global composer directly: `/usr/local/bin/composer require/remove/update ...`

Comment: Success! Running the process with /usr/local/bin/...    worked.