# Drush 12 Installation in Hosting Environments

Tags: drush

I'm running a Drupal hosting server, where the client's installation is below the directory

```
/var/www/<client-id>
```

The full path to any of the client's websites is

```
/var/www/<client-id>/htdocs/<drupal root>/web
```

The client is provided with a login to his *client-id* directory, where .bashrc lives, which sets the PATH to the vendor/bin directory -- but you can provide only one path per client, when a different PATH per *drupal root* would be needed.

**How can I set up drush or bash to use the proper *drupal root* comfortably?**

I know I could provide a script at *drupal root*, but if the client jumps between various *drupal root* installations, it might become cumbersome to also run the script before calling drush in the other *drupal root*.

Before 12, things where focused on *drupal root* and everything worked without any issues, as long as the user was in `<drupal root>/web`

---

Upgrade after I found out what bugged me in the first place:

With drush < 12, I could issue a drush command in any directory at or below 'web-root'. With a path ./vendor/bin, I will constrain myself to use drush from web-root only.

Is there a better way to solve this properly in a multi-site client installation as described above?

Comment: The [`drush-launcher` archived project's README](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush-launcher) recommends to set an relative path in the front of your `$PATH`: "Add `./vendor/bin` to the front of your `$PATH`."

Comment: In front, it can be a problem if you use core-dev, the local composer has priority over the global one. Better put it at the end: `export PATH="$PATH:./vendor/bin"` and remove any drush binaries still in global directories. To be sure check `which drush` and `which composer` from <drupal root> that drush is local and composer is global. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/317478/updating-drupal-9-5-to-drupal-10-fails-with-php-errors-what-should-php-include

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK Drush is built to work from `./drupal_root`, not from `./drupal_root/web`.

I'm using a similar setup to your's (not nested as deep though), my *current directory relative* path variable using the leading dot `./vendor/bin/` still works inside the respective drupal project roots:

My .bashrc looks like `PATH="/some/other/stuff:./vendor/bin:$PATH"`